# define class inside method from a performance POV

Tags: scala

I have a method that need return a `Iterator`. Then I defined a `CustomIterator` class inside that method and create instance of it as the return value.

It looks fine because only that method need to know about `CustomIterator`. But I'm afraid if this will produce too many `Class` instance as scala's type system is path-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `class` declaration will produce exactly one class file (that is, provided it does not contain inner classes or anonymous functions itself), so you shouldn't worry about that. Moreover, unless your program is supposed to run in a limited environment, additional classes won't cause any performance problems. In any case, you should profile your program before attempting such premature optimizations.

I'm not sure what you mean by "path-related type system". Is it path-dependent types? If so, this is a completely unrelated concept which exists in Scala type system only and does not affect actual class generation.